# Is tree.DecisionTreeRegressor a Model Tree or a Regression Tree?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tree

My understanding is that:

1. In a **Regression Tree**: the target value of each leaf is calculated as the mean of the target values of the instances that reached that leaf during training.
2. In a **Model Tree**: the value of each leaf is a linear function using a subset of the features, determined by performing a linear regression of the instances that reached that leaf during training.

Is the `tree.DecisionTreeRegressor` in scikit-learn a **Regression Tree** or a **Model Tree**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're understanding is right. Mathematically, a regression tree represents a [piecewise constant function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function), while a (linear) model tree is a [piecewise linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_function).

`DecisionTreeRegressor` is a regression tree.

Comment: Thanks. As I suspected. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @ben_0110100: no, but I'm one of the core devs for scikit-learn and I've hacked on the trees a bit over the last year.

Comment: @snarly can you suggest any Python realization of Model Tree, please?

Answer (score 0):

**Model Trees** differ from **Decision Trees** because they compute linear approximation (instead of constant ones) fitting simple **Linear Models** in the leaves.

For a project of mine, I developed [linear-tree](https://github.com/cerlymarco/linear-tree): *a python library to build Model Trees with Linear Models at the leaves.*

[image]

`linear-tree` is developed to be fully integrable with `scikit-learn`.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import *
from lineartree import LinearTreeRegressor, LinearTreeClassifier

# REGRESSION
regr = LinearTreeRegressor(base_estimator=LinearRegression())
regr.fit(X, y)

# CLASSIFICATION
clf = LinearTreeClassifier(base_estimator=RidgeClassifier())
clf.fit(X, y)
```

`LinearTreeRegressor` and `LinearTreeClassifier` are provided as `scikit-learn` BaseEstimator. They are wrappers that build a decision tree on the data fitting a linear estimator from `sklearn.linear_model`. All the models available in `sklearn.linear_model` can be used as linear estimators.

Compare **Decision Tree** with **Model Tree**:

[image]

[image]